# How to display smooth font for japanese site?

Tags: css, windows

In MacOS it display like this

[image]

but in Windows its not looking clean as in MAC

[image]

The font family i am using is

```
font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: normal;
```

site link: 
http://jp.baccarat.com/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9A%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88/2101057,ja_JP,pd.html?start=1&cgid=jewelry-pendants

Comment: That's not a lot of information! What format font are you using, where's your CSS? Help us to help you :)

Comment: Does Georgia support Japanese characters?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks have edited style plz check

Comment: i dont have idea please help me if you can

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks please you can suggest me if there any stylsheet i can add.

Comment: It's difficult to even try to make any suggestions with such a small amount of information. Can you show a live example? I am pretty sure Georfia is a font that doesn't include Japanese characters, so they OS's are using default fonts. But that's just speculation at this point.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks http://jp.baccarat.com/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9A%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88/2101057,ja_JP,pd.html?start=1&cgid=jewelry-pendants please check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found,

```
font-family:Meiryo
```

will be better for this languages.